# How to change user(client) discord activity?

Tags: c#, discord

please tell me how to implement a change in user activity? This code displays "playing in"

```
                    var activity = new Discord.Activity
                    {
                        Type = Discord.ActivityType.Listening,
                        Details = nowplaying["name"],
                        State = nowplaying["artist"] + albumFormatted,
                        Instance = true,
                    };
```

I already thought about doing a "binding" in python or nodejs for this case, but then you need to use a token there, which is not very convenient.

Can anyone suggest how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already figured out how to create and run a bot in C#, then you just need to use the `DiscordSocketClient.SetActivityAsync` method - here is your example in custom Discord bot's class which has `DiscordSocketClient` object as `client` field:

```
public void SetListeningStatus(string name, string artist, string albumFormatted) {
    Game activity = new(
        artist + albumFormatted,
        ActivityType.Listening,
        ActivityProperties.Instance,
        name
    );
    this.client.SetActivityAsync(activity);
}
```

There are other types of activities that can be viewed in the [Discord.NET Documentation](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.html) (enter `Game` in the class search) like `CustomStatusGame`, `RichGame`, `SpotifyGame` and `StreamingGame`. All of them are inherited from `Game` we use above. However, as I understand it, you need to make your own implementation of them, since they do not have public constructors.

Comment: I need change user RPC,not bot.

Comment: I've only worked with bots, but there may be a way to connect a user as a `DiscordSocketClient` object. Then the solution will be exactly the same